# Prysm is stuck because of Geth Bad block

Tags: go-ethereum, prysm

I run a full node with Geth+Prysm.

Tonight I had the following error with Prysm:

```
ethereum-prysm[40846]: time="2023-01-12 01:32:49" level=info msg="Finished applying state transition" attestations=128 payloadHash=0x806b46eadac2 prefix=blockchain slot=5554962 syncBitsCount=503 txCount=136
ethereum-prysm[40846]: time="2023-01-12 01:33:01" level=info msg="Synced new block" block=0xfb77310c... epoch=173592 finalizedEpoch=173590 finalizedRoot=0x220f4260... prefix=blockchain slot=5554963
ethereum-prysm[40846]: time="2023-01-12 01:33:01" level=info msg="Finished applying state transition" attestations=79 payloadHash=0x8123cf8667ff prefix=blockchain slot=5554963 syncBitsCount=506 txCount=135
ethereum-prysm[40846]: time="2023-01-12 01:33:12" level=warning msg="Pruned invalid blocks" blockRoot=0x85e0754c7e0555b263d1565d8b63b5e568b8bb477f7eff223003761decdfeab8 invalidChildrenCount=0 prefix=blockchain slot=5554964
thereum-prysm[40846]: time="2023-01-12 01:33:12" level=error msg="Could not handle p2p pubsub" error="could not process block: could not validate new payload: received an INVALID payload from execution engine" prefix=sync topic="/eth2/4a26c58b/beacon_block/ssz_snappy"
ethereum-prysm[40846]: time="2023-01-12 01:33:35" level=info msg="Peer summary" activePeers=45 inbound=0 outbound=45 prefix=p2p
ethereum-prysm[40846]: time="2023-01-12 01:34:35" level=info msg="Peer summary" activePeers=45 inbound=0 outbound=44 prefix=p2p
```

On Geth side there was:

```
ethereum-geth[2369376]: ########## BAD BLOCK #########
ethereum-geth[2369376]: Chain config: Chain ID:  1 (mainnet)
ethereum-geth[2369376]: Consensus: Beacon (proof-of-stake), merged from Ethash (proof-of-work)
ethereum-geth[2369376]: Pre-Merge hard forks:
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Homestead:                   1150000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/homestead.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - DAO Fork:                    1920000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/dao-fork.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Tangerine Whistle (EIP 150): 2463000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/tangerine-whistle.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Spurious Dragon/1 (EIP 155): 2675000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Spurious Dragon/2 (EIP 158): 2675000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/spurious-dragon.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Byzantium:                   4370000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/byzantium.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Constantinople:              7280000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/constantinople.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Petersburg:                  7280000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/petersburg.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Istanbul:                    9069000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/istanbul.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Muir Glacier:                9200000  (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/muir-glacier.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Berlin:                      12244000 (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/berlin.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - London:                      12965000 (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/london.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Arrow Glacier:               13773000 (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/arrow-glacier.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Gray Glacier:                15050000 (https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/gray-glacier.md)
ethereum-geth[2369376]: Merge configured:
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Hard-fork specification:    https://github.com/ethereum/execution-specs/blob/master/network-upgrades/mainnet-upgrades/paris.md
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Network known to be merged: true
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Total terminal difficulty:  58750000000000000000000
ethereum-geth[2369376]:  - Merge netsplit block:       <nil>
ethereum-geth[2369376]: Number: 16387164
ethereum-geth[2369376]: Hash: 0x8b7b464be774b1b19a825505d844cd71b491df3f067fd6695f76b93aff180ce4
ethereum-geth[2369376]:          0: cumulative: 302618 gas: 302618 contract: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 status: 1 tx: 0xe6cde65293c476c2593b2bc3dd7ec53d72c6e90db706de8399ea13e028a75282 logs: [0xc08d01e840 0xc08d01e8f0 0xc08d01e9a0 0xc08d01ea50] bloom: 0000000000010000000000004000000000000000800000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000001001000002000000010008000000000000000010000000080000002000000c000000000080000000000080000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000010000001000002000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000020000084000000000000000000080000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000800000000400000000000000000002000000001000000020000000000000 state:
ethereum-geth[2369376]:          1: cumulative: 743632 gas: 441014 contract: 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 status: 1 tx: 0xa629714febd2b8d10c3089433cc74e55a901628ad9271163f600f91dd6f94dd0 logs: [0xc08d01ec60 0xc08d01ed10 0xc08d01edc0 0xc08d01ee70 0xc08d01ef20 0xc08d01efd0 0xc08d01f080 0xc08d01f130] bloom: 00100000000000000000000000000020000000100000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000100000004000000000000000000008000001200000000200000000080001000000008002000000000200000000000000008000000000000000000000000210000040000000000020020000000000000000000000000000000004010000000001800000880000000000000000000000000000000200000000000002000000000200000000000012000000000000000000000000000000400000000000200800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002800000000000000000000 state:
```

Now Prysm is stuck with these messages:

```
ethereum-prysm[3125378]: time="2023-01-12 16:21:25" level=warning msg="Skip processing batched blocks" error="could not process block in batch: could not set node to invalid: invalid nil or unknown node" prefix=initial-sync
ethereum-prysm[3125378]: time="2023-01-12 16:21:25" level=info msg="Processing block batch of size 63 starting from  0xeb816d3c... 5555121/5559405 -estimated time remaining 22m40s" blocksPerSecond=3.1 peers=45 prefix=initial-sync
ethereum-prysm[3125378]: time="2023-01-12 16:21:25" level=warning msg="Skip processing batched blocks" error="beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0x621be8bc275fe1f87b163101676d1287f0e3cc6576b87dd65927b403ef161277 (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=5555121)" prefix=initial-sync
ethereum-prysm[3125378]: time="2023-01-12 16:21:25" level=info msg="Processing block batch of size 64 starting from  0x0ed33615... 5555185/5559405 - estimated time remaining 11m4s" blocksPerSecond=6.3 peers=45 prefix=initial-sync 
ethereum-prysm[3125378]: time="2023-01-12 16:21:25" level=warning msg="Skip processing batched blocks" error="beacon node doesn't have a parent in db with root: 0xdd0ec341b3c903ff82650d7ef5e3b7ba156deeb4fd88de9396536232d47b1d88 (in processBatchedBlocks, slot=5555185)" prefix=initial-sync
ethereum-prysm[3125378]: time="2023-01-12 16:21:35" level=error msg="Could not compute head from new attestations" error="head at slot 5554912 with weight 0 is not eligible, finalizedEpoch, justified Epoch 173589, 173590 != 173590, 173591" prefix=blockchain
ethereum-prysm[3125378]: time="2023-01-12 16:21:36" level=warning msg="Execution client is not syncing" prefix=powchain
ethereum-prysm[3125378]: time="2023-01-12 16:21:37" level=info msg="Processing block batch of size 64 starting from  0x8fe73bce... 5554929/5559406 - estimated time remaining 7m48s" blocksPerSecond=9.6 peers=46 prefix=initial-sync 
ethereum-prysm[3125378]: time="2023-01-12 16:21:47" level=error msg="Could not compute head from new attestations" error="head at slot 5554912 with weight 0 is not eligible, finalizedEpoch, justified Epoch 173589, 173590 != 173590, 173591" prefix=blockchain
```

and Geth with :

```
ethereum-geth[3128213]: WARN [01-12|17:26:02.662] Ignoring already known beacon payload    number=16,387,161 hash=606665..29f888 age=15h53m27s
ethereum-geth[3128213]: WARN [01-12|17:26:02.679] Ignoring already known beacon payload    number=16,387,162 hash=806b46..928430 age=15h53m15s
ethereum-geth[3128213]: WARN [01-12|17:26:02.701] Ignoring already known beacon payload    number=16,387,163 hash=8123cf..2da10f age=15h53m3s
```

Have you ever experienced this ? I cannot find what to do on stackexchange or Geth and Prysm doc.

Comment: How did you resolve it? I had a similar issue with geth lighthouse and it wasn't recovering itself after 20 minutes. Restarting everything solved it after a few minutes.

Comment: I went on Geth discord to ask. I have been told that it was probably DB corruption (since restarting everything several time was not fixing anything). I deleted Geth database and re-synced. I had tried to re-execute the block by moving the head before but it did not work.